# Not receiving data UDP

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I am trying to receive data, but it is taking FOREVER to receive.

I have tried a couple of things, like changing the Buffer size, but I am still not having any luck. This is to make me believe that it might not be an error with my code, but maybe the network.

```
import socket


UDP_IP = ''


UDP_PORT = 1500


BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
print("about to bind")


sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
  try:
      print('testing')

      message = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
      print("Got data:", repr(message))
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
      break
```

I am expecting to receive a message over the network. Thank you to all of those who reply in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as expected: it receives messages and prints them.

I tested it with the following command:

```
echo Hello | nc -u 127.0.0.1 1500
```

Make sure your router and local firewalls allow your UDP traffic through.

Comment: Thanks for showing how to easily generate UDP traffic